# Unable to resolve a local hostname with debian and monowall

Tags: dns, debian-squeeze

I'm using debian squeeze on my laptop, network is autoconfigured by DHCP(dhclient/network manager), Monowall is running on my home DSL router, the dns forwarder software is dnsmasq. I've added an A record for my wifi ap "ap.local" => 192.168.2.254

When i dig for ap.local, it returns me the good IP:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> ap.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9371
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ap.local.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ap.local.       0   IN  A   192.168.2.254

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 29 16:32:28 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 42
```

But when i ping ap.local the result is:

```
ping: unknown host ap.local
```

i can't use this name in my apps, nevertheless i can ping and use "ap"

Is there anyone here who can help me ?

here is my resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain local
search local
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add this line to it:

```
192.168.2.254 ap.local
```